# How to use NTLM authentication with Exchange on Android using Java?

Tags: java, android, ntlm

I'm working on an email client that needs to do NTLM authentication on the Android platform from Java. I've seen references to using Ksoap2, but nothing there seems to work.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, how? I've got basic authentication working fine, but would love to have NTLM working as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled around about this for awhile, and realized that using Apache's HTTPComponents was the easiest solution. I put a simple example of authenticating, and doing an Exchange Out of Office settings request at the following Git repo:

[NTLM and Basic Authentication with Exchange on Android, written in Java](https://github.com/bradparks/Exchange_SOAP_example_using_NTLM_and_BASIC_authentication_from_java_for_desktop_and_android)